# ignore optional combination of alphanumeric characters in str_extract

Tags: r, regex

I am working with street addresses.

I'm working in R

Luckily I know REGEX is a thing

Four examples for what we're dealing with might help. Bear in mind I have hundreds of addresses but i'm pretty sure that all of them come in one of these formats.

```
address <- "75b 126-194 amazing street town somecity 8300"
address_no_start <- "256 dumb street town somecity 47789 a country"
address_hwy <- "state highway 74 town somecity 8444"
address_no_numbers <- "green drive town somecity 8353"
```

My desired solution:

```
address <- "126 194 amazing street" (note the hyphen "-" is not wanted)
address_no_start <- "256 dumb street"
address_hwy <- "state highway 74 town"
address_no_numbers <- "green drive"
```

I have tried many combinations of things after doing some REGEX tutorials. The most success i've had is the following

```
address <- "75b 126-194 amazing street town somecity 8300"
pat <- ".+(?= (street|road|drive))"
str_extract(address, pat)
```

which results in:

```
"75b 126-194 amazing"
```

I can't figure out how to NOT get the 75b but retain the amazing street and also NOT have the hyphen "-".

And I can't get my head around trying to also match a pattern to the other 3  address types

An edit from someone below commenting: what I want is basically:

```
"(number if exists) (street name) (street|road|drive) or (state highway number)"
```

for every address

Comment: Not clear about the common pattern here

Comment: Have I asked something impossible? Because honestly I don't even see a common pattern in my ideal solution. I'm just trying to get "(number if exists) (street name) (street|road|drive) or (state highway number)" for every address.

Comment: regex works on some kind of patterns.  If there is nothing, it is difficult

Comment: It is possible, I will show you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addresses <- c("address", "address_hwy", "address_no_numbers", "address_no_start")

sub("-"," ",sub(".*?(\\S+\\s\\b[a-z]+.*)\\s+town.*","\\1",addresses))

[1] "126 194 amazing street" "state highway 74"       "green drive"            "256 dumb street"
```

Comment: That worked exactly the way I needed it to. Thank you so much!

Comment: Out of curiosity. In my example everything is called "town" and the regex includes a string "town". When I replace this with \\w* (for any alphanumeric - to include towns not called "town") I get everything after the town name as well as everything I wanted. How can I generalize your solution to towns not called "town"?

Comment: @kBORT You need to know where to stop. And that is the purpose of the word town. If you do not have town, then that means you need a different regex for that. It would be great if you ask another question giving the examples of what you have, and the output you desire to get. I might not be online, probably another person will give you an idea

Comment: Alright,  appreciate your help, I've actually managed to generalize it myself for most cases i'll amend my answer soon with your solution and a generalization. Just haven't got it working on the last case - we'll get there

Comment: which last case?@kBORT

Answer (score 1):

This is PCRE regex:

For "75b 126-194 amazing street town somecity 8300" use:

```
(?<=[0-9][a-z] ).+(?= (street|road|drive))
```

You will get

```
126-194 amazing
```

If you want to include street/road/drive, the "?:" is a non capturing group

```
(?<=[0-9][a-z] ).+ (?:street|road|drive)
```

To replace the "-" apply this replacement :

```
(?<=\d)-(?=\d) for ""
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot!

Comment: here to help you